# How can I create a jlabel & change its size while the program is running?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlabel

I am trying to create a weekly planner which can show the user what they have planned for the day. So if the user planned to be "studying math" from 5pm to 7pm on Monday, a jlabel of that size will show up under the monday tab and will span from 5pm to 7pm.

I am using the netbeans gui builder, and I dont know how to create a jlabel manually and while the program is running, and I also dont know how to change its vertical size.

Can you guys help me or point me in the right direction? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using the netbeans gui builder,

Well, you won't want to use a GUI builder if you want to add components dynamically. The code generated by the IDE will be too hard to maintain, so you will need to learn how to design and code a form manually

> I am trying to create a weekly planner

I would suggest you could use a `GridBagLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How To Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for the basics and working examples to get you started.

So you would start by creating an empty grid with just headings (days of the week) and column (hours of the day) labels.

Then when you want to add an activity you need to figure out which grid to add the activity to.

Once you figure out where to add the component the basics of add a component to a visible frame is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

> from 5pm to 7pm on Monday

The `gridheight` constraint will allow you to define the label to take up two cells on you planner.

Comment: Regarding the gui builder, is it possible for me to use both the gui builder and manually setting it with the GridBagLayout? Thanks

Comment: The drag and drop features of the GUI builder only work with whatever layout manager it is designed to be used. with. You can use the IDE to create your own forms with whatever layout manager you want to use. Although I have no idea how to do this since I don't use an IDE.

Comment: @Anon, I guess you can create the initial UI using the UI builder. And then take that generated code as a starting point and do manual changes. But after you do the manual changes, you will not be able to use UI builder again to do further changes.

Comment: I have one more question, is it possible to create jlabels while a program is running? I am using netbeans btw.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create and add jlabels to UI in runtime.

Comment: @Anon Don't use the IDE to generate the original form. As I told you the IDE will generated layout code that is to complex to maintain. `is it possible to create jlabels while a program is running?` - already answered and I even showed you the code to do this.

Comment: @camickr Thanks a lot I was lost before asking and now I have a good idea of what to do. I created a jpanel within my jframe, is it possible for me to manually edit the contents of that jpanel (using the tips given here) while the other jpanels are gui generated?